# where should I put my data that will not be discarded while programs on In MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I have a experience with devel UWP and code behind structure.
I'm new to MVVM design, and I'm developing UWP App with Template, MVVM Basic.

I'm developing a simple App that generate numbers for lotto. To help understanding, I posted my App picture.
[image: my App]

I implemented with ViewModel with main page. below is my source.

#### In Mainpage.Xaml

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel._display_game, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="TextBlock">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Text,Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="Click Me" Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.game_create}"/>
```

#### MainPage.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new MainViewModel();

    public MainPage()
    {
        DataContext = ViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

#### MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : Observable
{
    public ObservableCollection<TextBlock> _display_game { get; set; }

    private int[] game;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        game_create = new RelayCommand(ExecuteClick);
    }
    private void ExecuteClick()
    {
        {  //generating 6 random value 
            _display_game = new ObservableCollection<TextBlock>();
            game = new int[6];
            Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            for (int t = 0; t < 6; t++)
            {
                bool[] check = new bool[46];
                _display_game.Add(new TextBlock());

                int dup = 0;
                int cnt = 0;
                while (cnt < 6)
                {
                    int tmp = random.Next(1, 46);
                    if (check[tmp] == false)
                    {
                        check[tmp] = true;
                        game[cnt] = tmp;
                        cnt++;
                        //_display_game[t].Text += $"{tmp} ";
                    }
                    else dup++;
                }
                Array.Sort(game);
                _display_game[t].Text += string.Format("{0} 게임 : ", t+1);
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) _display_game[t].Text += $"{game[i]} ";
            }
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("_display_game");
    }
    public RelayCommand game_create { get; set; }
}
```

and the question is here. as I know, ViewModel is a part of View. So, I navigated Page, Listview Items are refreshed(I mean they are gone). but I want to make them alive whatever user does, except user clicks fresh button.

**I want to make my data available even I'm out of page and comeback. and I want use this data at another page also.**

when I do code behind(I think I don't have any pattern before), I put the any codes to anywhere to achieve my goal. if I want to use this page's data at another page, then I just passed list as parameters to another page's overloaded OnNavigated Method.

but, I'm new to MVVM, and I often become afraid of myself violating MVVM rules. so I post this question.

I'm sorry for long question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do it but first I will tell you the way you already know so you are comfortable with it.

> You can still pass the list of data to next page as parameter when you navigate to the next page. the only difference is before in **code behind** you used to send ** _display_game** directly as parameter now you just need to send **ViewModel. _display_game** as parameter and remaining logic on your **OnNavigatedTo** on next page will remain same as before, and on next page you can receive that parameter and even set to the

```
ViewModel.listofNextPage = e.Parameter as ObservableCollection<TextBlock>
```

but that depends what you want to do on your next page.

Now I will just give a little hints of other possible methods so that you know your options.

you can use [NavigationCacheMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode) property of the page to **Required** and this way the data on that page will remain saved even if you go to other pages and come back.

Another way can be using a **Static Class** as a service which will hold the collection of your data. and that collection will also be static this way you can access that collection of data anywhere in your application.

> **Tip** : Do not use **TextBlock** as the type in your collection instead just use string if you need only 1 property or make a custom class like following :

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Text { get ; set ; }
}
```

then make collection of this type as following :

```
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> _display_game { get; set; }
```

change the datatype of your itemtemplate :

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="MyClass">
```

Because TextBlock is a UI control so it is best that it is used for that purpose only, and for databinding just use normal classes.